# Converting Tree to JavaTree to SonarQube rule

Tags: java, casting, sonarqube

I need to convert a Tree to a JavaTree. But i am getting ClassCastException, obviously.

```
public Javadoc(Tree tree) {
    if (tree.is(METHOD_KINDS)) {
        elementParameters = ((MethodTree) tree).parameters().stream().map(VariableTree::simpleName)
                .map(IdentifierTree::name).collect(Collectors.toList());
        elementExceptionNames = ((MethodTree) tree).throwsClauses().stream().map(Javadoc::exceptionName)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (tree.is(CLASS_KINDS)) {
        elementParameters = ((ClassTree) tree).typeParameters().stream().map(TypeParameterTree::identifier)
                .map(IdentifierTree::name).map(name -> "<" + name + ">").collect(Collectors.toList());
        elementExceptionNames = Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
        elementParameters = Collections.emptyList();
        elementExceptionNames = Collections.emptyList();
    }



    List<String> javadocLines = cleanLines(PublicApiChecker.getApiJavadoc((JavaTree)tree));
    mainDescription = getDescription(javadocLines, -1, "");
    blockTagDescriptions = extractBlockTags(javadocLines, Arrays.asList(BlockTag.values()));
    undocumentedNamedTags = new EnumMap<>(BlockTag.class);
}
```

It happens in jadocLines variable. I have just a Tree, but i need to set a JavaTree for that getApiJavadoc, because of some methods and classes that it calls forward. I tried to create a javatree object and give my tree data to it. But i couldn't, 'cause JavaTree class is abstract. JavaTree class have other classes inside, but i am not getting this. Can anyone helps me in that part?

Edit 1 :  Thanks for answers, but i cannot create another class as simples as that, because i need to give some arguments to the class i need that i do not have(because it dont even exist). The class i need to instantiate is:

```
public static class ImportTreeImpl extends JavaTree implements ImportTree {
    private final boolean isStatic;
    private final Tree qualifiedIdentifier;
    private final SyntaxToken semicolonToken;
    private final SyntaxToken importToken;
    private final SyntaxToken staticToken;

    public ImportTreeImpl(InternalSyntaxToken importToken, @Nullable InternalSyntaxToken staticToken,
                          Tree qualifiedIdentifier, InternalSyntaxToken semiColonToken) {
      super(Kind.IMPORT);
      this.importToken = importToken;
      this.staticToken = staticToken;
      this.qualifiedIdentifier = qualifiedIdentifier;
      this.semicolonToken = semiColonToken;
      isStatic = staticToken != null;
    }
```

This class is inside JavaTree class and i need to instatiate it, but i dont have any SyntaxToken, and I cant create a null one to put here just for instantiate it. Can you help with this part?

OBS1: That JavaTree cast is wrong, i know, that was just a test. But Thank you!

EDIT2:I know that getApiChecker need a tree, but the problem is not the getApiChecker, but some methods that are called after. Look:

```
List<String> javadocLines = cleanLines(PublicApiChecker.getApiJavadoc(tree));
```

Calls :

```
 @Nullable
  public static String getApiJavadoc(Tree tree) {
    if (!tree.is(API_KINDS)) {
      return null;
    }
    ModifiersTree modifiersTree = getModifierTrees(tree);
    // FIXME token should be retrieved in a much simpler way.
    if (modifiersTree != null && !(modifiersTree.modifiers().isEmpty() && modifiersTree.annotations().isEmpty())) {
      return getCommentFromTree(modifiersTree);
    }
    if (tree.is(Tree.Kind.METHOD)) {
      MethodTree methodTree = (MethodTree) tree;
      return getCommentFromMethod(methodTree);
    }
    return getCommentFromTree(tree);
  }
```

That calls :

```
private static String getCommentFromTree(Tree tokenTree) {
    return getCommentFromSyntaxToken(FirstSyntaxTokenFinder.firstSyntaxToken(tokenTree));
  }
```

That calls:

```
@Nullable
  public static SyntaxToken firstSyntaxToken(@Nullable Tree tree) {
    if (tree == null || tree.is(Tree.Kind.INFERED_TYPE)) {
      return null;
    } else if (tree.is(Tree.Kind.TOKEN)) {
      return (SyntaxToken) tree;
    }
    for (Tree next : ((JavaTree) tree).children()) {
      SyntaxToken syntaxToken = firstSyntaxToken(next);
      if (syntaxToken != null) {
        return syntaxToken;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

And my problem is :

```
for (Tree next : ((JavaTree) tree).children()) {
```

Because this is trying to make that cast, that bugs everything. And i can't change this last one, because this is a sonar code, and i can't change it.

Comment: Please, post the code of your sonar rule.